# Grant access to all the users within a table

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-grant

Currently, I am granting access to my colleagues using the following code:

Grant select on tablename to user1, user2, user3 with grant option;

However, I created a table that contains the user id and name and my goal is to grant access to a certain table to all the users within the column that contains the list of active users.

Something like: Grant select on database.tablename to (select userid from table_ative_users) with grant option;

I used to do it using a Stored Procedure but right now, I can't use it, so, I am looking for an alternative.

Many thanks

Comment: Dynamic SQL is only allowed in SPs. You can create the GRANT commands based on this table and the cut&paste&run.

Comment: You can use a middleware solution, like open a cursor in Java, form a query and submit it against the backend for each record you are fetching.